# Gradient for starting Backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation, theory

I was reading this nice tutorial about Pytorch's basics:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html

In the first example (pure Numpy), the author starts the backward phase by setting as his "first" gradient the numerical result of the loss function calculation **multiplied by the constant `2`**:

```
grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
```

Why does he multiply by `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the loss assumption is the (Mean) Squared Error $\mathcal{L} = (\hat{y} - y)^2$ and the derivative is

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}} \mathcal{L} = 2 (\hat{y} - y)
$$

which is then passed "backward" for use in the chain rule.

Comment: Oh my goodness..  Don't know why I 'removed' the square from my train of thoughts... Thanks, and apologies..